# Bind to item in collection, code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-controls

I want to bind to a specific item of my itemsControl (named maskDataBinding). I tried this:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding,Path=[0]}"/>
```

but it doesnt work. Also, could I bind the index as well? I have a slider and would like to update the item it is binded to when I adjust the slider.

Something like this:

```
<VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding,Path=[{Binding ElementName=ScaleXSlider, Path=Value]}"/>
```

Edit:
Here is maskDataBinding simplified

```
<!--Outer collection-->
<ItemsControl Name="maskDataBinding">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!--nested collection-->
            <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSource}>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Background="Transparent"</Canvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Name}"</Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: please add some more details like what is maskDataBinding, what is sub item, it is difficult to understand the issue from the code in question. as a guess you may try `{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding,Path=Items[0]}"` or `{Binding ElementName=maskDataBinding,Path=Children[0]}"`

Comment: @pushpraj maskDataBinding is an itemsControl. Its items are also itemControls. The nested itemControl's ItemsPanel is a Canvas. I want to bind to these Canvases.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly you want to bind Visual to the first Canvas panel of the inner items control. correct me I read it differently.

Comment: @pushpraj Correct. But if its possible, Id like to bind the index as well, so that I can change which Canvas panel it is binded to from a slider value.

Comment: binding index is no possible, but you may bind SelectedItem using a Selector if needed.